# Parent method using a variable defined in a child class

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

In Python you can do:

```
class Binance(Exchange):
    name = "Binance"
    code = "binance"
```

and in the parent class have

```
class Exchange:
    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls):
    return cls.name
```

#### Now Perl!

This is lovely. I want the same for my Perl objects.

```
package DWDESReader;
use base qw(DWConfigFileReader);
our $type = "DES";
```

and in the base class:

```
package DWConfigFileReader;

our $type = "";

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    $args{type} = $type;

    return bless {%args}, $class;
}

sub getType {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{type};
}
```

But this doesn't work, i.e. only returns the empty string assigned in the base class. I didn't expect it to work but am unsure how it should be done.

Comment: Why do you need it? Variables aren't inherited, only methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes don't have attributes (variables) in Perl, only methods (subs).

I recommend creating an abstract virtual class method.

```
package DWConfigFileReader;

use Carp qw( croak );

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    my $self = bless(\%args, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub type { croak("Subclass must override \"type\"."); }

1;
```

```
package DWDESReader;

use parent 'DWConfigFileReader';

sub type { "DES" }

1;
```

You don't even need `$self->{type} = $class->type;`; just use `$self->type` instead of `$self->{type}`.

Comment: All of these answers are excellent; however, in the constructor of the parent, I check whether a given (file) parameter is set and if not, I croak at the user mentioning the type. `if (!exists($args{file}) { croak($self->type." file not set"); }`. This does not work as in the base class $self->type causes the "override croak". I could of course just set some bogus information like 'config' in the base class. But that's not exactly what I intended. Any ideas?

Comment: @bluppfisk, Sounds like you incorrectly used `bless`. See the code in my answer.

Comment: I'm not using a reference to %args (because otherwise Perl complains about an odd number of elements), and I also had to declare type before new otherwise I cannot use it in my constructor, but otherwise I don't see what's wrong. I always get "subclass must override" now in my child classes.

Comment: I meant the second parameter. It should be the class of the object, not the base class.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I understand what you were saying: define $self first as a blessed class, then set its properties afterwards. That way you can refer to $self->type.

I was composing the %args list first and doing the blessing at the very end, which of course does not allow you to use $self->type. It does, however, mean that you have to create an object before you know you can. But that's nitpicking. Thank you!

Comment: Re "*define $self first as a blessed class, then set its properties afterwards.*", Naw, just my stylistic choice so that the constructor of the base class and of the derived class look the same. That's not the issue at all.

Comment: Re "*It does, however, mean that you have to create an object before you know you can*", Or use `$class->type` (as long as `type` is meant to be called as a class method rather than an object method)

Comment: Oh wonderful. I didn't realise I could use `$class` as something else than a string. Clearly a Perl noob here. Thank you for your expert guidance.

Comment: A string is a perfectly fine invocant --`Foo->new` is used as a shortcut for `"Foo"->new`, after all-- as long as that's what the method expects.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why one should need it, but it's possible, if you turn off [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) `refs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package My::Base;

    sub new { bless {}, shift }
    our $name = 'Base';
    sub get_name {
        my ($self) = @_;
        my $class = ref $self || $self;
        do { no strict 'refs';
             ${ $class . '::name' }
         }
    }
}

{   package My::Child;
    use parent -norequire => 'My::Base';
    our $name = 'Child';
}

my $ch = 'My::Child'->new;
print $ch->get_name, ' ', 'My::Child'->get_name;
```

But usually, you would just define a class method holding the name:

```
{   package My::Base;

    sub new { bless {}, shift }
    sub name { 'Base' }
    sub get_name { shift->name }
}

{   package My::Child;
    use parent -norequire => 'My::Base';
    sub name { 'Child' }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As has been suggested, Perl inherits methods (subs), not variables, but constants are actually subs, so you can do something similar like this.

```
package DWDESReader;
use base qw(DWConfigFileReader);
use constant TYPE => "DES";
```

Then, if you call `$self->TYPE` somewhere in the base class, you'll get "DES" if the object is actually a DWDESReader object.

Comment: any reason why you'd prefer constant over a sub as in ikegami's answer?

Comment: Constants are actually implemented as subs, so our answers aren't all that different. Constants do have the advantage that they can be part of compile-time optimisation, but not in cases where they are called as methods, so it's not a terribly significant distinction. I would actually prefer ikegami's approach if it were anticipated that some types might be variable rather than constant, but I prefer mine if the value really is understood to be a class constant.